# Execute Redis command with server timeout

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

Is there a way to execute a command in Redis, where you supply a server-side timeout?

For example, I want to execute a command that can take more than 3 sec.
In that case, I would want that the Redis server will stop the execution of the command after 3 sec (with no correlation to the client timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

You can do if and only if the command is made that way, e.g. [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) command.